# graduated pattern polygon fill

Tags: qgis, polygon, style

I'm sure this question is really really basic but I appeal to you because I hate the idea that I have spent 20 minutes trying to do such a simple thing...

All I want to do is style a polygon layer by increasing complexity of a pattern.

ex. low value polygons will have very spaced out lines, high values will have lots of lines very close to each other...

Again, I know this sounds incredibly low level, but I need some help.